# Trouble converting a large raster to polygon using R

Tags: r, polygon, raster, r-raster

I have a rather large raster (384 MB) that I am trying to convert to a polygon shapefile in R.
The `rastertoPolygons` function from the raster package doesn't seem to be able to handle this, as I tried running it but gave up after it was going for 7+ hours.

I also tried to use gdal_polygonize.py from GDAL in python via [this function by John Baumgartner](https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/26e8091f082f2b3dd279) but after letting the function run for 30+ minutes I still have nothing. Am I simply not letting it run long enough? I was under the impression that gdal_polyonize.py was supposed to be very quick, i.e. seconds.

[Here's a link to my raster file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tnzl64vgql5ltv/top6loss.tif?dl=0)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`terra` does this much faster than `raster` (but not faster than GDAL because that is what it uses)

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("top6loss.tif")
```

Note that you have 22 billion cells (that is a lot by most standards, and that is why it takes a while):

```
ncell(r)
#[1] 21989436765
```

It finishes in 10 minutes on my laptop

```
system.time(p <- as.polygons(r))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 562.34    3.54  568.77 

p
#class       : SpatVector 
#geometry    : polygons 
#dimensions  : 6, 1  (geometries, attributes)
#extent      : -13.54777, 12.33558, -6.134633, 9.781491  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

These are the 6 values

```
as.data.frame(p)
#  top6loss
#1     2254
#2     5418
#3    13623
#4    14344
#5    15885
#6    19654
```

You can save the file with

```
writeVector(p, "cells.shp")
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you so much!